# generate classes from schema

Tags: java, jaxb

I have jdk1.6 and using Eclipse Juno verion and class path is set to jdk1.6.

I have created the JAXB project and set project face of it to use JAXB 2.1 and JDK1.6.

But when try to generate Java classes from XSD, I am getting below error message.

as for as I understand if we have JDK 1.6, we don't need to have any other JAXB jars in the build path of the project.

Error:
The classpath for this project does not appear to contain the necessary libraries to proceed with class generation.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No my friend you have to also add jaxb-api jar to your build path it doesn't comes with JDK

Download jax-B from here https://jaxb.java.net/ and puts “jaxb-api.jar” and “jaxb-impl.jar” on your project classpath i.e. in your buildpath

but I will prefer that you have to create the maven project, so you will have to add only dependencies in your project and maven will download these dependencies from maven repo, if you have not define any repository in maven settings.xml and it make your project light-weight as well

Comment: i tried that as well. but many documentations say not required if you have jdk 1.6

Comment: basically the jar in that site is saying corrupted jar,tried couple of times

Comment: @mahesh see this http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/ and you can try this also for downloading jars http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaxbapi22jar.htm

Comment: @mahesh is it helps you then write click on my answer so it will be helpful for others at stackoverflow

Comment: @mahesh are you still struggling